# Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'. Expected ':' and instead saw '.'. Unclosed regular expression. Unrecoverable syntax error.

Tags: reactjs

Babel is properly compiling my code without errors but JSHint is showing below errors.

**Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'. 
Missing semicolon. 
Expected ':' and instead saw '.'. 
Unclosed regular expression. 
Unrecoverable syntax error. (14% scanned).**

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id='root'></div>
```

**JS (Babel):**

```
function List(props){
  return <li>{props.message}</li>;
}

function ToDoList(){
    const todos = ['learn', 'code', 'practise'];
    return (
        <ul>
            {todos.map((message) => <List key={message} message={message} />)}
        </ul>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToDoList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSHint might not support JSX (or some ES6 features for that matter). I recommend switching to ESLint. https://eslint.org/

Comment: @kingdaro when using ESLint, it is throwing **Parsing error: Unexpected token <**

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, the babel-eslint parser has to be enabled: https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint